# How do I get the text from the selected div not including its childrens text using .textContent

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to try and print out the textContent of the div I pass to the function. I only want the selected divs text, not its childrens too.

I have seen a few examples, but all use jquery which I do not want :)

```js
function changeText(element){

var thisEl = document.getElementById(element);

console.log(thisEl.textContent)

}

changeText('container')
```

```html
<div id = 'container'>
  this is a test 1
  <div>
    this is a test 2
    <div>
      this is a test 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the first of the element's [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), which will be the [text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Text) in question. Note that text nodes are sensitive to white space.

```js
function changeText (element) {
  var thisEl = document.getElementById(element);

  console.log(thisEl.childNodes[0].nodeValue);

}

changeText('container');
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  this is a test 1
  <div>
    this is a test 2
    <div>
      this is a test 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeText(elementId) {
   var childs = [].slice.call(document.getElementById(elementId).childNodes);
   var text = '';
   childs.forEach(function (child) {
      if (child.nodeType === 3) {
         text += child.nodeValue || '';
      }
   });
   return text;
}
```

Comment: It is a fast way to get slice method of Array.prototype

Comment: @DmitriyLoskutov Actually, it's the slow way, considering it has to actually construct an instance of an Array.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need only the selected text? https://github.com/timdown/rangy But you can get also the outer Element of your selected text.

Answer (score 0):

using `.textContent` and `childNodes[0]`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   
</head>

<body>
  <div id='container'>
    this is a test 1
    <div>
      this is a test 2
      <div>
        this is a test 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <output id="out"></output>
  <script>
    var tgt = document.getElementById("container").childNodes[0].textContent
     document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = tgt;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```